# Issue in creating ports with GoJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, port, gojs

I am testing the GoJS library for Javascript.
I'm looking to create ports on the sides of a group.
I attach an executable extract from the program.

When I create a new object from the palette, right-click on the object, and select "Add left port", the debugging message shows that the variable "arr" is declared "undefined" at execution. (program lines 111 and 112).

Thank you for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Dynamic Ports</title>
<meta name="description" content="Nodes with varying lists of ports on each of four sides." />
<!-- Copyright 1998-2017 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="../release/go-debug.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/goSamples.js"></script>  <!-- this is only for the GoJS Samples framework -->
<!-- LL <script>goCode("diagramEvents", 600, 200)</script>-->
<script src="/Users/leonlevy/gojs/site/extensionsTS/ResizeMultipleScript.js"></script>
<span id="diagramEventsMsg" style="color: red"></span>
<span id="changeMethodsMsg" style="color: red"></span>
<span id="BackgroundDoubleClicked" style="color: red"></span>
<p>
<script id="code">
  function init() {
    if (window.goSamples) goSamples();  // init for these samples -- you don't need to call this
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;  //for conciseness in defining node templates
    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
        {
          allowDrop: true, // from Palette
          // what to do when a drag-drop occurs in the Diagram's background
          mouseDrop: function(e) { finishDrop(e, null); },
      //   layout:  null, // Diagram has no layout
/*            $(go.GridLayout,
              { wrappingWidth: Infinity, alignment: go.GridLayout.Position, cellSize: new go.Size(1, 1) }),*/
          initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
          "commandHandler.archetypeGroupData": { isGroup: true, category: "OfGroups" },
          "undoManager.isEnabled": true
        });
        // LL
        function showMessage(s) {
          document.getElementById("diagramEventsMsg").textContent = s;
        }
    // when the document is modified, add a "*" to the title and enable the "Save" button
    myDiagram.addDiagramListener("Modified", function(e) {
      var button = document.getElementById("SaveButton");
      if (button) button.disabled = !myDiagram.isModified;
      var idx = document.title.indexOf("*");
      if (myDiagram.isModified) {
        if (idx < 0) document.title += "*";
      } else {
        if (idx >= 0) document.title = document.title.substr(0, idx);
      }
    });

myDiagram.addDiagramListener("ObjectSingleClicked",
    function(e) {
      var part = e.subject.part;
      var heightPart = part.actualBounds.height;
      var widthPart = part.actualBounds.width;
      var xPart = part.actualBounds.position.x;
      var yPart = part.actualBounds.position.y;
      var xMouseClic = myDiagram.lastInput.documentPoint.x;
      var yMouseClic = myDiagram.lastInput.documentPoint.y;
      var xPartMiddle = xPart+ widthPart/2;
      var side = xMouseClic<= xPartMiddle ? "Left" : "Right";
       if (!(part instanceof go.Link)) {console.log("hello leon");}
    });
    myDiagram.addDiagramListener("BackgroundSingleClicked",
        function(e) {
                    showMessage("Clicked on background " + myDiagram.lastInput.documentPoint);
                                          //console.log("hello leon");}
        });


myDiagram.addDiagramListener("BackgroundDoubleClicked", // LL KO
    function(e) {
                  showMessage("Double-clicked at " );//+ e.myDiagram.lastInput.documentPoint);
                  //showMessage("Clicked on " + myDiagram.lastInput.documentPoint);
    });

myDiagram.addDiagramListener("ClipboardPasted",
    function(e) { showMessage("Pasted " + e.myDiagram.selection.count + " parts"); });
// LL end

    // To simplify this code we define a function for creating a context menu button:
    function makeButton(text, action, visiblePredicate) {
      return $("ContextMenuButton",
               $(go.TextBlock, text),
               { click: action },
              //{showMessage( "button: " + myDiagram.lastInput.button);
               // don't bother with binding GraphObject.visible if there's no predicate
               visiblePredicate ? new go.Binding("visible", "", function(o, e) { return o.myDiagram ? visiblePredicate(o, e) : false; }).ofObject() : {});
              //}
            }
    var nodeMenu =  // context menu for each Node
      $(go.Adornment, "Horizontal",
                  makeButton("Add left port",
                             function (e, obj) { addPort("left"); }),
                  makeButton("Add right port",
                             function (e, obj) { addPort("right"); }),

      ); //Leon end nodeM

        // Add a port to the specified side of the selected nodes.
        function addPort(side) {
          myDiagram.startTransaction("addPort");
          myDiagram.selection.each(function(node) {
            // skip any selected Links
            if (!(node instanceof go.Node)) return;
            // compute the next available index number for the side
            var i = 0;
            while (node.findPort(side + i.toString()) !== node) i++;
            // now this new port name is unique within the whole Node because of the side prefix
            var name = side + i.toString();
            // get the Array of port data to be modified
            var arr = node.data[side + "Array"];
            showMessage ("node: " + node + "; name: " + name + ";arr: " + arr + ";node.data: " + node.data);
            if (arr) {
              // create a new port data object
              var newportdata = {
                portId: name,
                portColor: go.Brush.randomColor()
                // if you add port data properties here, you should copy them in copyPortData above
              };
              // and add it to the Array of port data
              myDiagram.model.insertArrayItem(arr, -1, newportdata);
            }
          });
          myDiagram.commitTransaction("addPort");
        }

    var portSize = new go.Size(8, 8);
    // this function is used to highlight a Group that the selection may be dropped into
    function highlightGroup(e, grp, show) {
      if (!grp) return; showMessage("ok")
      e.handled = true;
      if (show) {
        // cannot depend on the grp.diagram.selection in the case of external drag-and-drops;
        // instead depend on the DraggingTool.draggedParts or .copiedParts
        var tool = grp.diagram.toolManager.draggingTool;
        var map = tool.draggedParts || tool.copiedParts;  // this is a Map
        // now we can check to see if the Group will accept membership of the dragged Parts
        if  (grp.canAddMembers(map.toKeySet())) {
          grp.isHighlighted = true;
          return;
        }
      }
      grp.isHighlighted = false;
    }
    // Upon a drop onto a Group, we try to add the selection as members of the Group.
    // Upon a drop onto the background, or onto a top-level Node, make selection top-level.
    // If this is OK, we're done; otherwise we cancel the operation to rollback everything.
    function finishDrop(e, grp) {
      var ok = (grp !== null
                ? grp.addMembers(grp.diagram.selection, true)
                : e.diagram.commandHandler.addTopLevelParts(e.diagram.selection, true));
      if (!ok) e.diagram.currentTool.doCancel();
    }
    var portMenu =  // context menu for each port
      $(go.Adornment, "Vertical",
        makeButton("Remove port",
                   // in the click event handler, the obj.part is the Adornment;
                   // its adornedObject is the port
                   function (e, obj) { removePort(obj.part.adornedObject); }),
        makeButton("Change color",
                   function (e, obj) { changeColor(obj.part.adornedObject); }),
        makeButton("Remove side ports",
                   function (e, obj) { removeAll(obj.part.adornedObject); })
      );

            // support double-clicking in the background to add a copy of this data as a node
            myDiagram.toolManager.clickCreatingTool.archetypeNodeData = {
              name: "Unit",
              leftArray: [],
              rightArray: [],
              topArray: [],
              bottomArray: []
            };

      myDiagram.groupTemplateMap.add("OfGroups",
        $(go.Group, "Table",
        { locationObjectName: "BODY",
          locationSpot: go.Spot.Center,
          selectionObjectName: "BODY",
          contextMenu: nodeMenu
        },
          {
            background: "transparent",
            resizable: true,
            // highlight when dragging into the Group
            mouseDragEnter: function(e, grp, prev) { highlightGroup(e, grp, true); },
            mouseDragLeave: function(e, grp, next) { highlightGroup(e, grp, false); },
            //computesBoundsAfterDrag: true,
            mouseDrop: finishDrop,
            resizable: true, resizeObjectName: "SHAPE"
            //, minSize: new go.Size(36, 46)
          },
        new go.Binding("background", "isHighlighted", function(h) { return h ? "rgba(0,0,255,0.)" : "transparent"; }).ofObject(),
          // save the modified size in the model node data
        new go.Binding("desiredSize", "size", go.Size.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Size.stringify),
        new go.Binding("location", "loc", go.Point.parse).makeTwoWay(go.Point.stringify),
        $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
          { fill: null, stroke: "rgba(0,50,255,1)", strokeWidth: 3, name: "SHAPE"}),
        $(go.Panel, "Vertical",  {alignment: go.Spot.Top},// title above Placeholder
          $(go.Panel, "Horizontal",  // button next to TextBlock
            { stretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal, background: "rgba(0,0,255,0.1)" },
            $("SubGraphExpanderButton",
              { alignment: go.Spot.Right, margin: 5 }),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              { //text: "verticalAlignment: Top", verticalAlignment: go.Spot.Top,
                alignment: go.Spot.Left,
                editable: true,
                margin: 5,
                font: "bold 18px sans-serif",
                opacity: 0.75,
                stroke: "#404040"
              },
              new go.Binding("text", "text").makeTwoWay())
          ),  // end Horizontal Panel
          $(go.Placeholder,
            { padding: 5, alignment: go.Spot.TopLeft })
        ),  // end Vertical Panel
        // the Panel holding the left port elements, which are themselves Panels,
        // created for each item in the itemArray, bound to data.leftArray
        $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
          new go.Binding("itemArray", "leftArray"),
          { row: 1, column: 0,
            itemTemplate:
              $(go.Panel,
                { _side: "left",  // internal property to make it easier to tell which side it's on
                  fromSpot: go.Spot.Left, toSpot: go.Spot.Left,
                  fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer",
                  contextMenu: portMenu },
                new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),
                $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
                  { stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
                    desiredSize: portSize,
                    margin: new go.Margin(1,0) },
                  new go.Binding("fill", "portColor"))
              )  // end itemTemplate
          }
        ),  // end Vertical Panel
        // the Panel holding the right port elements, which are themselves Panels,
        // created for each item in the itemArray, bound to data.rightArray
        $(go.Panel, "Vertical",
          new go.Binding("itemArray", "rightArray"),
          { row: 1, column: 2,
            itemTemplate:
              $(go.Panel,
                { _side: "right",
                  fromSpot: go.Spot.Right, toSpot: go.Spot.Right,
                  fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer",
                  contextMenu: portMenu },
                new go.Binding("portId", "portId"),
                $(go.Shape, "Rectangle",
                  { stroke: null, strokeWidth: 0,
                    desiredSize: portSize,
                    margin: new go.Margin(1, 0) },
                  new go.Binding("fill", "portColor"))
              )  // end itemTemplate
          }
        ),  // end Vertical Panel
        )
     );  // end groupTemplateMap.add("OfGroups"
      // initialize the Palette and its contents
      myPalette =
        $(go.Palette, "myPaletteDiv",
          {
            groupTemplateMap: myDiagram.groupTemplateMap,
            layout: $(go.GridLayout, { wrappingColumn: 1, alignment: go.GridLayout.Position })
          });

          myPalette.nodeTemplate =
          $(go.Node, "Horizontal",
            $(go.Shape,
              { width: 10, height: 10, fill: "white" },
              new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
            $(go.TextBlock,
              new go.Binding("text", "color"))
          );

          myPalette.model = new go.GraphLinksModel([
            { key: 101, text: 'UNIT', isGroup: true, isSubProcess: true,
                category: "OfGroups", isAdHoc: true,  loc: '0 0' },

          ]);

        }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<!-- LL -->
<body onload="goIntro()">
<div id="container" class="container-fluid">
<div id="content">
<div id="sample">
  <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
      <div id="myPaletteDiv" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 2px; background-color: whitesmoke; border: solid 1px black"></div>
      <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="flex-grow: 1; height: 480px; border: solid 1px black"></div>
    </div>
  <p>
    See the <a href="../intro/ports.html">Ports Intro page</a> for an explanation of GoJS ports.
  </p>
    <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:250px">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the node is bound to the correct data.  In particular, the data object should have a `leftArray` property that is an Array holding port descriptor objects. (And it seems to expect a `rightArray` property too.)  You can determine the expected properties for each **Node** by looking at the source property names of each of the **Binding**s that are in the node template.

You can determine the expected properties for each of the port descriptors in either data Array by looking at the properties that the **Panel.itemTemplate** uses in its data **Binding**s.

Comment: Hello Walter thank you for your advices.
I checked the bindings itemArray and leftArray, portId and portId:
I think that arrays are created in the node by this statement:  myDiagram.toolManager.clickCreatingTool.archetypeGroupData = { 
              name: "Unit",
              leftArray: [],
              rightArray: [],
              topArray: [],
              bottomArray: []
            };
Am I right ?
I tried other modifications like "archetypeGroupData"  instead of "archetypeNodeData".
Sorry, I did not found any other issue.

Can you help, more?

Thanks,
Leon

Comment: I was asking what your model data was.

Comment: There was no model. I added         myDiagram.model = $(go.GraphLinksModel); but it didn't change anything.

Comment: That's an empty model, so the Diagram wouldn't show anything.  Please give an example of the model data that you want to be represented by a node.

Comment: The model data should have 4 ports for the left side of the node, and 4 ports for the right side.

Comment: The model data have two arrays named leftArray and rightArray.

Comment: Walter, I added myPalette.model = new go.GraphLinksModel([
            { key: 101, text: 'UNIT', 
            leftArray: [], rightArray: [],
            isGroup: true, isSubProcess: true,
                category: "OfGroups", isAdHoc: true,  loc: '0 0' },

          ]); and it started showing ports. Not t the correct side but that I think I can debug. Many thanks for your great help. Leon